# Install nuget package : EntityFramework 6 in .NETStandard 2.0 class library

Tags: entity-framework-6, .net-standard-2.0

I installed nuget package: EntityFramework 6 in .NET Standard2.0 Class library. On building the project I am getting the below warning message:

**NU1701:Package 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.**

Does it mean that we cannot use EntityFramework 6 in .NETStandard 2.0 class library?

Can anyone help me here by providing their inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...]. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Entity Framework 6 will be compatible with a project that target `.NET Framework` but will not be compatible with a project that target `.NET Core`

The answer is yes, you can use EF6 with `.NET Standard 2.0` class library as long as you plan to only support `.NET Framework`

Microsoft already announced they plan to release a version of `EF6` that support `.NET Core` at the end of 2019.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Classic](https://entityframework-classic.net/)

Entity Framework Classic is an EF6 fork. It's everything you like about EF6, but with better performance, must-have features, .NET Core support, and more.

It's currently the only option available to use a `EF6` fork on a project that target `NET Core`

There is a free `Community` version that includes pretty much everything and an `Enterprise` version that include additional features.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your quick and detailed response. It helped me a lot to understand the issue in details :).